# Locate and Get in single operation in KMIP(Key Management Interoperability Protocol)

Tags: java, kmip

Has anyone used a locate and get operation in single kmip request .I am getting a error because it's difficult to operate at same time.
As u can see the kmip request i am sending to my server.

```
<RequestMessage>
  <RequestHeader>
    <ProtocolVersion>
      <ProtocolVersionMajor type="Integer" value="1"/>
      <ProtocolVersionMinor type="Integer" value="2"/>
    </ProtocolVersion>
    <Authentication>
      <Credential>
        <CredentialType type="Enumeration" value="UsernameAndPassword"/>
        <CredentialValue>
          <Username type="TextString" value="vijans"/>
          <Password type="TextString" value="asdf1234"/>
        </CredentialValue>
      </Credential>
    </Authentication>
    <BatchOrderOption type="Boolean" value="1"/>
    <BatchCount type="Integer" value="2"/>
  </RequestHeader>
  <BatchItem>
    <Operation type="Enumeration" value="Locate"/>
    <UniqueBatchItemID type="ByteString" value="31303030303031"/>
    <RequestPayload>
      <Attribute>
        <AttributeName type="TextString" value="Name"/>
        <AttributeValue>
          <NameValue type="TextString" value="new_ss_nv"/>
          <NameType type="Enumeration" value="UninterpretedTextString"/>
        </AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
    </RequestPayload>
  </BatchItem>
  <BatchItem>
    <Operation type="Enumeration" value="Get"/>
    <UniqueBatchItemID type="ByteString" value="31303030303032"/>
    <RequestPayload/>
  </BatchItem>
</RequestMessage>
```

this is not valid because the get operation doesn't evolve use of unique identifier.can help somebody?

Answer (score 2):

Your KMIP server must implement the ID placeholder mechanism. It's a temporary Unique Identifier variable to cache the identifier between batch items in a request
(see the [Client-to-Server Operations](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.4/os/kmip-spec-v1.4-os.html#_Toc490660840) section in the specification).

You can see for each operation how this ID placeholder must be used or saved. An extract from the [Locate operation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.4/os/kmip-spec-v1.4-os.html#_Toc490660849):

> The server returns a list of Unique Identifiers of the found objects,
>   which then MAY be retrieved using the Get operation. [...]. If a
>   single Unique Identifier is returned to the client, then the server
>   SHALL copy the Unique Identifier returned by this operation into the
>   ID Placeholder variable.  If the Locate operation matches more than
>   one object, and the Maximum Items value is omitted in the request, or
>   is set to a value larger than one, then the server SHALL empty the ID
>   Placeholder, causing any subsequent operations that are batched with
>   the Locate, and which do not specify a Unique Identifier explicitly,
>   to fail.

In the Get operation, the [Get Request Payload table](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.4/os/kmip-spec-v1.4-os.html#_Toc467307661) specifies that the Unique Identifier is not required and describes that:

> If omitted, then the ID Placeholder value is used by the server as the
>   Unique Identifier.

Then for the *Locate operation*, if the Locate results with one single Unique Identifier, the server must cache the value in the ID placeholder (independently of the next operation), else it must empty the ID placeholder.

Finally for the *Get operation*, if the Unique Identifier is not defined in the request, the server must make the operation with the ID placeholder. If the ID placeholder is empty, the operation must fail with a result like "Invalid Field" (i'm not sure about that result reason but that makes sense to me).